# Цикл for в C# и вычисление условий.

Tags: .net, c#

Есть функция вида:

```
string MyFunc(string input)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Lenght; i++)
    {
        //разнообразные вычисления, например такие:
        input = input.Replace("bla", "bla1");
        //а здесь рекурсивный вызов:
        input = MyFunc(input);    
    }
}
```

Внутри выполнился выход за приделы строки. То есть в условии:

```
if (input[i] == 'b')
```

Собственно вопрос:
Для цикла for, запись i < input.Lenght вычисляется один раз? Получается, что строка input уменьшается, а (i < input.Lenght) остается const?
И сразу как бы этого избежать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего, проблема в том, что Вы пытаетесь обратиться к строке по индексу ПОСЛЕ рекурсивного вызова. Когда строка уже укорочена рекурсивным вызовом, а в текущем вызове i < input.Length отработало для предыдущей длины строки.

Comment: Ага, так и есть. Спасибо.

Comment: Починил, хм спасибо. У мну из условия в условие бегало и не выходило из цикла когда нужно.